# Snipe-IT: Email notification URL link is broken (pointing to localhost)

Tags: php, laravel-artisan

It might be a frequent question, could you help me to solve my issue.

I am using snipe-IT to manage our assets.
https://snipeitapp.com/

I set it up and configured everything to start usage.
Almost all work fine for us, except a matter of URL links to snipe-it on notification mails.

The url link on the mail indicates to http://localhost/.
I thought it relates to APP_URL in .env file though, I have configured the setting. (believe it's proper setting), but it didn't affect to notification mails.
Other emails (e.g.: passward reset mail) are affected, and they show links properly.

Let me know where I can configure the base url for notification mails.

To submit notification mail, I executed command below:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/snipe-it/artisan snipeit:expiring-alerts
```

Best regards,

Yusuke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I did resolve this soon by myself.
I could find an answer in GitHub issue in snipe-it repository.

https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it/issues/5880

I tried executing a command below, got notification mails with proper url links are dispatched.

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

Thank you for taking a look.

I hope this will help anyone who faced to same trouble.